# Highcharts - adding a question mark where data is missing in a bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I want to add a question mark to a Highcharts bar chart where data in the data set is null, because the value zero is shown in the same way as when the data is null. Is this possible?

EDIT I mean column chart

Comment: Show us a minimal example with some code we can play with.

Comment: I will make one, but I need some time as I use backbone and don't need to include that code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X8Scf/

Comment: I have tried with a marker, but it is not showing: http://jsfiddle.net/X8Scf/1/

Comment: Another one that isn't working but I think I am closer: http://jsfiddle.net/X8Scf/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. You need to set the point to zero for the formatter to know where to draw the image:

```
var series = [8, 7, 8, null, 9]


$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Example null values'
        },
        series: [{
            name: "values",
            data: series,
            type: "column",
            zIndex: 0,
            color: "#55F26A"
        }],
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                        if(this.y == null) {
                            this.point.update(0);
                            return "<img src='http://placehold.it/20'/>";

                        }
                        else return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    });
});
```

try it at http://jsfiddle.net/X8Scf/4/